# Variable seams to be nonassigned when later called upon

Tags: python

I am making a program that lets you guess the number from 0 to a given number g. But a function which starts a new game seams to never define the variable.

```
import random
g = 100
def new_game():
    secret_number = random.randint(0,g)
    return secret_number
def input_guess(x):
    x = int(x)
    print "guess was",x
    if x > secret_number:
        print "lower"
    elif x < secret_number:
        print "higher"
    if x == secret_number:
        print "correct"
new_game()
input_guess(33)
```

No matter what I change it seams to always say that secret_number isn't defined

```
NameError: name 'secret_number' is not defined
```

any help?

Comment: I am sorry, this code only works because I never call it. If you add an guess like input_guess(33) it will reproduce. I will do so too in the original

Comment: `secret_number` is local to the `new_game` method.  Although called on the penultimate line, it is never assigned to a variable.  Furthermore, the use of such global variables is frowned upon.

Comment: You should make `secret_number` a parameter of `input_guess`.

Answer (score 1):

`secret_number` is a local variable in `new_game()` function, so, you have to store it globally:

`secret_number = new_game()`

or

pass secret_number as an argument to `input_guess()`:

```
def input_guess(x, secret_number):
    x = int(x)
    print "guess was",x
    if x > secret_number:
        print "lower"
    elif x < secret_number:
        print "higher"
    if x == secret_number:
        print "correct"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here, one is to make `secret_number` a global variable, so it can be accessed by any function, however this is generally not a great option, as @alexander said, and so this is not the suggested way:

```
import random
g = 100
def new_game():
    global secret_number
    secret_number = random.randint(0,g)
    return secret_number
def input_guess(x):
    global secret_number
    x = int(x)
    print "guess was",x
    if x > secret_number:
        print "lower"
    elif x < secret_number:
        print "higher"
    if x == secret_number:
        print "correct"
new_game()
input_guess(33)
```

What I have done here is made it so that there is the global `secret_number` variable, which means that that variable is the same in all methods.

The better way to do this would be to store the value of `secret_number` once returned, and pass that as a parameter to `input_guess`:

```
import random
g = 100
def new_game():
    secret_number = random.randint(0,g)
    return secret_number
def input_guess(x, secret_number):
    x = int(x)
    print "guess was",x
    if x > secret_number:
        print "lower"
    elif x < secret_number:
        print "higher"
    if x == secret_number:
        print "correct"
number = new_game()
input_guess(33, number)
```

This makes it so that `number` is equal to the `secret_number` returned by `new_game()` and then feeds that variable into `input_guess()` to give it the secret number.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    import random
    g = 100
    def new_game():
        secret_number = random.randint(0,g)
        return secret_number
    def input_guess(x, secret_number):
        x = int(x)
        print "guess was",x
        if x > secret_number:
            print "lower"
        elif x < secret_number:
            print "higher"
        if x == secret_number:
            print "correct"
    secret_number = new_game()
    input_guess(33, secret_number)
```

It's because the `secret_number` was not a global variable, so the `input_guess` method didn't know "what it was".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I managed to kinda solve it myself, which is kinda like Joykills answer

```
import random
g = 100
secret_number = 0
def new_game():
    global secret_number
```

that way I access the global variable secret_number and am allowed to change it in my function

```
    secret_number = random.randint(0,g)
    return secret_number
def input_guess(x):
    x = int(x)
    print "guess was",x
    if x > secret_number:
        print "lower"
    elif x < secret_number:
        print "higher"
    if x == secret_number:
        print "correct"
new_game()
input_guess(33)
```